# pip install packages in Python runing into errors

Tags: python

I am trying to install a few packages in Python. For example trying to install `quantmod` but was told to upgrade my `pip` which I did through Anaconda prompt but when I go to try and install `quantmod` again I get the same error message. This happens with all packages I am trying to install...

I am running `pip install quantmod` and to upgrade `pip` this `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

```
    (base) C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32>pip install quantmod

    Collecting quantmod
      Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement quantmod (from versions: )

    No matching distribution found for quantmod
    You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

    (base) C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32>python -m pip install --upgrade pip

    Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\USER\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (10.0.1)

    (base) C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32>pip install quantmod

    Collecting quantmod
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement quantmod (from versions: )

    No matching distribution found for quantmod
    You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

EDIT 1 with `pip install --upgrade pip`:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 487, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install, finder)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 428, in _check_skip_installed
    req_to_install, upgrade_allowed)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "C:\Users\USERR\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 811, in get_page
    inst = cls(resp.content, resp.url, resp.headers)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 731, in __init__
    namespaceHTMLElements=False,
TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding'
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(base) C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32>
```

EDIT:

```
(base) C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32>pip install Gensim
Collecting Gensim
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 811, in get_page
    inst = cls(resp.content, resp.url, resp.headers)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 731, in __init__
    namespaceHTMLElements=False,
TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding'
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Have you tried `pip install --upgrade pip` directly?

Comment: Yes I did try that

Comment: `quantmod` is an R package, no such Python package exists AFAICT...

Comment: On further investigation, there's [this](https://github.com/jackwluo/py-quantmod) which claims to be pip installable, but no such package actually exists on pypi: https://pypi.org/search/?q=quantmod . I think you'll need to clone the repo and install manually if you want to use this one

Comment: Have you tried using conda to update: `conda update pip`

Comment: Using `conda update pip` I get the following: `(base) C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32>conda update pip
Solving environment: -` and Python stops working and closes down and then reopens.